# Extracting multiple slots from S4 object into a single matrix

Tags: r, r-s4

I have an S4 object (object) with multiple slots (Slot1, Slot2, Slot3). I've been able to write individual slots to tables by using:

```
    tablename <- as.matrix(object@Slot1)
    write.csv(tablename, file = "C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop")
```

However, I'd like to write, say, Slot1 and Slot2 to the same matrix but I've been unable to figure out how to do so. I've tried

```
   tablename <- as.matrix(object@Slot1, object@Slot2)
```

and received the error

```
   Warning messages: 1: In if (rownames.force %in% FALSE) NULL else if (rownames.force %in%  : the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
   2: In if (rownames.force %in% TRUE) row.names(x) else if 
   (.row_names_info(x) <=  :
   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I'm not sure how else to do this, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: if object@Slot1 and object@Slot2 have same number of column, you could `rbind(as.matrix(object@Slot1),as.matrix(object@Slot2))`

Comment: Can you post `dput(object)`?

Comment: denis Thanks; I tried that, but looks like they don't have the same number of columns.

Rui Barradas I ran that, but got pages and pages of what looked like this: 10065L, 10078L, 10122L, 10145L, 10169L, 10170L, 10185L, 10189L, 
10204L, 10220L, 10234L, 10290L, 10305L, 10331L, 10355L, 10475L, 
10511L, 10583L, 10592L, 10609L, 10626L, 10645L, 10667L, etc.